# Error en lista con .sort y .split en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Resulta que al estar haciendo un programa con lista en python, me dieron un problema donde me entregan todos los valores de entrada juntos (como se muestra en el ejemplo) y me pedían que en una nueva lista los ordenara de menor a mayor.

```
lista=input("Ingrese los numeros: ")
lista=lista.split(",")
largo=len(lista)
lista2=[]
while largo>0:
    lista2.append(lista[largo-1])
    largo=largo-1
lista2.sort()
print(lista2)
```

El problema es que el tipo de entrada siempre sera así **250,150,90,100,10,40,170,160,80,160,70,30**.
Al ingresar estos datos, me vi obligado a usar el .split para que se ordenaran en la lista y al querer ordenarlos de menor a mayor con .sort, me di cuenta que la salida de valores no eran los correctos:

**EJEMPLO**

**Entrada**:
*Ingrese los numeros*

**Al ingresar los valores (250,150,90,100,10,40,170,160,80,160,70,30)**

**Salida:**
*['10', '100', '150', '160', '160', '170', '250', '30', '40', '70', '80','90']*

Como resultado, no se ordena la lista de menor a mayor como esperaría, ¿Por qué pasa esto? La única idea que se me ocurrió es que haya sido problema del .split o algo así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este ocurre porque el resultado de `.split()` no es una lista de integer, pero es *una lista de string*.

Asi, cuando hace `lista=lista.split(",")`, el resultado es:

```
['250', '150', '90', '100', '10', '40', '170', '160', '80', '160', '70', '30']
```

Para solucionarlo, tiene que convertir los *strings* a *integer*. Una metoda sencilla es usar el funcion `int()` dentro del bloque while:

```py
while largo>0:
    lista2.append(int(lista[largo-1]))
    largo=largo-1
```

En esta manera, lista2 será una lista de integer y el sort funcionará bien.

Answer (score 2):

Como señala [@Luke](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/139272/luke) el método `split()` retorna una lista de *string* que tienen otro criterio de ordenación distinto al de una lista numerica.

Considerando lo anterior la solución es convertir cada string en entero/flotante usando el método int/float a cada elemento, para hacerlo sencillo se puede usar el método `map()` que retorna un *iterable* que debe convertirse a una lista usando `list()`:

```py
lista = input("Ingrese los numeros: ")
numbers = list(map(int, lista.split(",")))
numbers.sort()
print(numbers)
```

Salida:

```
[10, 30, 40, 70, 80, 90, 100, 150, 160, 160, 170, 250]
```

Answer (score 0):

Podria sugerir resolverla con el clásico for

```py
  lista = input("Ingrese los numeros: ")
  numeros = [int(x) for x in lista.split(',')]
  numeros.sort()
  print(numeros)
```

Salida:

```sh
  [10, 30, 40, 70, 80, 90, 100, 150, 160, 160, 170, 250]
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que dan varias respuestas a tu problema, puedes solucionar también tu inconveniente realizando el ordenamiento previo a el Split, ya que el único objetivo que tiene en tu código parece ser de presentación de output

Comment: A esta respuesta le falta mayor detalle, quizás algo de código o una explicación detallada de cómo propones resolver el problema y algún ejemplo. Para más información te invito a leer [answer].

Answer (score 0):

esta sentencia de *una linea* obtiene entrada del usuario para luego convertirlo y devolver un arreglo ordenado.

```
sorted(map(int, input().split(',')))
```

sim embargo puedes compararlo con otras soluciones:

```
>>> def test(lista):
...     largo = len(lista)
...     lista2 = []
...     while largo>0:
...         lista2.append(int(lista[largo-1]))
...         largo-=1
...     return sorted(lista2)
...
>>> times = timeit.Timer(partial(test, ['10', '100', '150', '160', '160', '170', '250', '30', '40', '70', '80','90'])).repeat(3, 1000)
>>> min(times)/1000
1.7498400004114956e-05
```

```
>>> def test(lista):
...     numbers = list(map(int, lista.split(',')))
... 
...     numbers.sort()
...     return numbers
...
>>> min(times)/1000
1.1956699992879294e-05
```

```
>>> def test(lista):
...     numeros = [int(x) for x in lista.split(',')]
...     numeros.sort()
...     return numeros
...
>>> times = timeit.Timer(partial(test, '10,100,150,160,160,170,250,30,40,70,80,90')).repeat(3, 1000)
>>> min(times)/1000
1.334649999625981e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres convertir la lista antes de ordenarla, es posible ordenarla usando el atributo `key` para conseguir que se ordene según su valor numérico entero:

```py
lista = input("Ingrese los numeros: ")
lista = lista.split(",")
lista_ordenada = sorted(lista, key=int)
print(lista_ordenada)
```

Es conveniente chequear que todos los elementos de la lista son números enteros:

```py
lista = input("Ingrese los numeros: ")
lista = lista.split(",")
assert all(x.isdigit() for x in lista)
lista_ordenada = sorted(lista, key=int)
print(lista_ordenada)
```